# Facebook no longer posts a panoramic photo as a 360 photo

Tags: iphone, photos, facebook

In the past, I have posted panoramic photos on Facebook, and Facebook posted them as 360 photos.

Recently I have been unable to get Facebook to post any panoramic photo as a 360 photo; instead Facebook will just post it as a really wide photo. I'm using the same camera (iPhone SE) as I did before when Facebook posted them as 360 photos.

This problem occurs with both the Facebook website and the Facebook app.

How can I get Facebook to post panoramic photos as 360 photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently some metadata in the photos is missing, which is odd, because the photos that I'm uploading to Facebook are direct from my phone - I never modified them.

I found a utility called [Exif Fixer](https://exiffixer.com/) that adds any missing metadata that Facebook requires. I ran it on one of my panoramic photos using the default settings, then uploaded the photo to Facebook, and Facebook finally recognized it was a panorama and posted it as a 360 photo.

I used [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) to see what metadata was added that fixed the problem, and these are the tags that were added:

```
[XMP]           XMPToolkit                      : Image::ExifTool 10.10
[XMP]           CroppedAreaImageHeightPixels    : 3872
[XMP]           CroppedAreaImageWidthPixels     : 16382
[XMP]           CroppedAreaLeftPixels           : 0
[XMP]           CroppedAreaTopPixels            : -1936
[XMP]           FullPanoWidthPixels             : 16382
[XMP]           ProjectionType                  : cylindrical
[XMP]           UsePanoramaViewer               : True
```